# datetime string formatting in usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to formatting a Date field in user control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("Date")).ToString("MMM dd")  %>'></
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This output is like these ; `Jan 15`, `Oct 23`
But I want to set Turkish culture these. So want to take results turkish lang opposite.

How to do this?
Best regards...

Comment: What culture did you set in your page?

Comment: May be you have to do some thing like this on page <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="_Default" Culture = "tr-TR" %>

Comment: @AbdulSaboor UICulture="tr-TR" Culture="tr-TR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Change the display directive:

```
Text='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("Date")).ToString("dd MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)  %>'
```

In your `Web.config` file add the following under `<system.web>` node (this will set the culture for all pages):

```
<globalization culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR"/>
```

Or, set the `Culture` and `UICulture` attributes in the `@Page` directive (this will set the culture only for the specified page) like this:

```
<%@ Page UICulture="tr-TR" Culture="tr-TR" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the culture on page like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Culture = "tr-TR" %>
```

OR
You can set culture with programming [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)